# Best cheap mic for personal use into computer

Tags: microphone

I've been using Windows Sound Recorder to record myself playing music. On the new laptop I just got, the recordings are very, very bass heavy and distorted. What is a good cheap microphone that I could plug into my computer and use for this purpose? Or am I best off using some headphones as a microphone?

Comment: "Or am I best off using some headphones as a microphone?"   o_O  While it is possible to record sound from some headphones, why do you think this would be "best"?

Comment: @endolith I mean would this be the best value for my limited purposes

Comment: But recording through headphones would be worse than recording though a microphone

Answer (score 2):

That depends very much on your needs for said microphone.
 
If you are looking for a decent quality of recordings of yourself sitting in the room playing at home, I think a possible solution could be a microphone with a USB interface and a stand to mount the microphone on.
These are available in many price and quality ranges in most of the online music-/recording-equipment stores, such as sweetwater, zzsounds, musiciansfriend and amazon.

Alternatively your laptop probably has a 1/8" mono jack input (AKA mini-jack) for a microphone, which can be used to connect a microphone (if need be with a converter-cable from 1/8" jack to an XLR plug). However you will not be able to use microphones of the condenser type this way, since these require a power source, which is usually provided by a mixer or preamplifier, but is not present on a standard laptop mic input. Condensers have some advantages over dynamic microphones (although some are a matter of taste), and might suit your need better than a dynamic mic.

Answer (score 2):

The microphone may or may not even be the weakest link.  Consumer mic jacks are not designed for quality, they are designed to be cheap.  Often, the analog to digital conversion is an after thought to the design and primarily designed for being able to talk in to the computer which requires far less fidelity than trying to feed an instrument or singing.  Many consumer mics designed to work with such a jack are also fairly low fidelity.

You can get some mics that offer reasonable quality that will work well if you have a good quality audio jack, such as those designed for use with the 1/8 inch jacks on many DSLRs, however unless your audio jack is decent quality, it won't matter a whole lot.

Your best bet is really to get a cheap audio interface that is designed with sound quality in mind and get an actual professional mic, but then you are looking at spending $100-$150 minimum for prosumer gear or more like $300 to really get good gear, so that might still be out of your price range.  That said, even a basic decent quality mic at the consumer level is probably going to run you a decent amount.  (I'd guess $50 to $100, though I don't follow that part of the market closely.)